# Can't OAuth with Facebook; what are my next debugging steps?

Tags: python, django, facebook, oauth-2.0

I've got a Django template that initiates the [Facebook OAuth process](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) by doing:

```
window.location='https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A//localhost%3A8000/fbpanel/explore-python'
```

Then, in my Django view, I get the resulting code as follows:

```
import cgi
import urllib

# [...]

code = request.GET['code']
args = {
    'client_id': MY_CLIENT_ID,
    'redirect_uri': 'http://localhost:8000/fbpanel/explore_python'
    'client_secret': MY_CLIENT_SECRET,
    'code': code,
}
url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?' + \ 
        urllib.urlencode(args)

raw_response = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
response = cgi.parse_qs(raw_response)    

if response:
    error = ''
    if response['access_token']:
        access_token = response['access_token'][0]
    if response['expires']:
        expires = response['expires'][0]
else:
    access_token = 'No access token returned'
    expires = 'No expiration given'
    error = raw_response
```

Invariably, `response` is `None` and `raw_response` contains `Error: {"error":{"message":"Error validating verification code.","type":"OAuthException"}}`

The same credentials validate fine with the [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). I was binding my server to `localhost` in that case too, and have `localhost:8000` set in my official app domain. Before I did that, the JavaScript wouldn't work. After, it did. So I don't think `localhost` is the issue.

I've manually stepped through the code, printing the `code` returned by FB out,
then manually running the above code line by line in the python interpreter, and
I can't see anything I'm doing wrong. What are my next debugging steps? The FB
documentation offers little guidance if you receive an `OAuthException`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code either, although I'm not great with python. I also doubt the localhost is the problem, as I would expect the error message to mention redirect_uri in that case (which it should do if you mangle the redirect_uri param on purpose as a test). Have you tried printing out the value of `url` and entering it manually into the browser location bar?

Comment: I just noticed...you have `explore-python` (with a hyphen) in one place and `explore_python` (with an underscore) in another...is that in the actual code?

Comment: That was it, @FloydWilburn. If your redirect_uri doesn't *exactly* match in the token request and the code request, FB will fail to authenticate you. If you move your suggestion to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value used for `redirect_uri` must be exactly the same when you request the token as it was when you requested the code. Since no actual redirect occurs when requesting the token, it can be easy to miss small differences. The error message is not particularly descriptive in this case; what it really means is "The parameters you are sending don't correspond with the code value you are sending".

Comment: Great, thanks. I've opened a [docbug with Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/243049145752532).